# Import SQL data into Hbase table via Hive

Tags: hive, hbase, sqoop, impala

I have created an Hbase table via Hive.
I want to be able to query this data with impala once it has landed in Hbase and have version history that is native to Hbase.

However when I want to import data from a MS SQL server.
At the end of the sqoop job, I get the following error message:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10101]: A non-native table cannot be used as target for LOAD
```

Comment: The error message is clear: you can map a Hive table on an HBase table, so that you can SELECT the HBase data *(full scan in batch mode)*. But for loading data you need a more direct approach. Suggested readings: an excerpt of "Hadoop for dummies" http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/importing-data-into-hbase-with-sqoop.html then a post on Ingest Tips that adds Oozie in the mix http://ingest.tips/2015/02/12/sqoop-hbase-oozie/

Comment: strange, in the documentation of Hive it seems to state that inserts are possible ... https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration#HBaseIntegration-Overwrite

Comment: Maybe it depends on the version of Hive Metastore, the version of HBase, the version of Sqoop, the configuration of all three, the possible presence of security plug-ins (Sentry, Ranger), and the way you defined your Hive table. Honestly, I would rather go the easy way -- native Sqoop to HBase load -- than investigate that integration mess... and if ever the mess is sorted out, check the overall performance.

Comment: One would expect proper composition of said compatibility in CDH

Comment: Cloudera promises *stability* at the cost of not having the latest version of anything. Maybe you hit a bug that was fixed months ago in the Apache distro, but was not deemed important enough to back-port to CDH.